# How to get content of S/Mime message with OpenSSL or PHP?

Tags: encryption, openssl, certificate, pki

Please find below the header of a message that I've received. I'm working on the AS2 protocol. I can send messages, but I am having some issues when I receive them.

```
Date: Fri, 28 Jun 2013 13:22:03 GMT
From: XXXXXXX
Message-ID: XXXXXXXXXX
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: application/pkcs7-mime; smime-type=enveloped-data;  name=smime.p7m
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=smime.p7m
Disposition-Notification-To: XXXXXXXX
Disposition-Notification-Options: signed-receipt-protocol=optional, pkcs7-signature;            signed-receipt-micalg=optional, sha1
Receipt-Delivery-Option: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx
EDIINT-Features: CEM, multiple-attachments, AS2-Reliability
AS2-Version: 1.2
AS2-To: YYYY
AS2-From: XXXX
Content-Length: 59074
```

Could you show me how to get the content using either OpenSSL or PHP?
On the most commands I execute it gives me this errors:

```
Error reading S/MIME message
140224062383968:error:0D07207B:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_get_object:header too long:asn1_lib.c:150:
140224062383968:error:0D0D106E:asn1 encoding routines:B64_READ_ASN1:decode error:asn_mime.c:193:
140224062383968:error:0D0D40CB:asn1 encoding routines:SMIME_read_ASN1:asn1 parse error:asn_mime.c:528:
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have fed the header instead of the content into the ASN.1 BER decoder. BER encodes ASN.1 defined data structures into a binary encoding. Feeding strings into a BER decoder will always generate errors like the one above.

Instead you should probably first decode the base 64 encoding of the content, and feed the resulting binary data into a decoder that accepts CMS data (CMS has been specified using ASN.1 and uses BER/DER encoding).

Answer (score 0):

According to `Content-Type: smime-type=enveloped-data`, this seems to be an S/MIME encrypted email. You should be able to decrypt it with openssl like so:

```
openssl smime -decrypt -in email.eml -recip recipient.pem
```

where `recipient.pem` is your (or the recipient's) private key in PEM format.

If you don't have your private key in PEM format, you can extract and convert it from a PKCS#12 file:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in recipient.p12 -out recipient.pem
```